# windows vista booting problems

Tags: windows-vista, boot

Please see the log below and advise.

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance
Date:          11-09-2010 11:26:45
Event ID:      100
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      Event Log
User:          LOCAL SERVICE
Computer:      RMS-PC
Description:
Windows has started up: 
     Boot Duration      :   191577ms
     IsDegradation      :   false
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   11-09-2010 05:53:11
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance" Guid="{cfc18ec0-96b1-4eba-961b-622caee05b0a}" />
    <EventID>100</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>4002</Task>
    <Opcode>34</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000010000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-09-11T05:56:45.455Z" />
    <EventRecordID>18132</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-9B8C-0001-9BEC-4C9E7551CB01}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="2064" ThreadID="3448" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>RMS-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="BootTsVersion">2</Data>
    <Data Name="BootStartTime">2010-09-11T05:53:11.905Z</Data>
    <Data Name="BootEndTime">2010-09-11T05:56:36.470Z</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemBootInstance">3150</Data>
    <Data Name="UserBootInstance">2929</Data>
    <Data Name="BootTime">191577</Data>
    <Data Name="MainPathBootTime">120673</Data>
    <Data Name="BootKernelInitTime">44</Data>
    <Data Name="BootDriverInitTime">6230</Data>
    <Data Name="BootDevicesInitTime">6445</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPrefetchInitTime">70831</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPrefetchBytes">400531456</Data>
    <Data Name="BootAutoChkTime">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootSmssInitTime">5772</Data>
    <Data Name="BootCriticalServicesInitTime">2209</Data>
    <Data Name="BootUserProfileProcessingTime">1481</Data>
    <Data Name="BootMachineProfileProcessingTime">1145</Data>
    <Data Name="BootExplorerInitTime">91243</Data>
    <Data Name="BootNumStartupApps">13</Data>
    <Data Name="BootPostBootTime">70904</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsRebootAfterInstall">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseStepImprovementBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseGradualImprovementBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseStepDegradationBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootRootCauseGradualDegradationBits">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsDegradation">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsStepDegradation">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsGradualDegradation">false</Data>
    <Data Name="BootImprovementDelta">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootDegradationDelta">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootIsRootCauseIdentified">false</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>


Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance
Date:          11-09-2010 11:26:38
Event ID:      203
Task Category: Shutdown Performance Monitoring
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Event Log
User:          LOCAL SERVICE
Computer:      RMS-PC
Description:
This service caused a delay in the system shutdown process: 
     File Name      :   iphlpsvc
     Friendly Name      :   
     Version        :   
     Total Time     :   10606ms
     Degradation Time   :   6232ms
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   11-09-2010 05:48:17
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance" Guid="{cfc18ec0-96b1-4eba-961b-622caee05b0a}" />
    <EventID>203</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>4007</Task>
    <Opcode>41</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000010000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-09-11T05:56:38.467Z" />
    <EventRecordID>18131</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-66C8-0000-9BEC-4C9E7551CB01}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="2064" ThreadID="3456" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>RMS-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="StartTime">2010-09-11T05:48:17.833Z</Data>
    <Data Name="NameLength">9</Data>
    <Data Name="Name">iphlpsvc</Data>
    <Data Name="FriendlyNameLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="FriendlyName">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="VersionLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Version">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="TotalTime">10606</Data>
    <Data Name="DegradationTime">6232</Data>
    <Data Name="PathLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Path">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="ProductNameLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ProductName">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="CompanyNameLength">0</Data>
    <Data Name="CompanyName">
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Voting to move on Superuser as this is not programming related. Either way though, I don't think anybody can help you with the information provided (those logs are also called "dumps" - for good reason ;) ... you should add much more information about your problem.

Comment: I advise you to ask this on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

It means it is taking too long to shut down, it identifies the service that is causing the delay.

> This service caused a delay in the system shutdown process
>        File Name      :   iphlpsvc
>        Total Time     :   10606ms
>        Degradation Time   :   6232ms

This iphlpsvc is a service to help ipv4 have ipv6 connectivity, solving it is another issue.  http://wiki.blackviper.com/wiki/IP_Helper

If this error is logged every time you shut down the PC, then it may be a problem, it it only does it every once in a while, I would ignore it. If you do not notice a considerable delay in shutdown, I would ignore the error completely.

If it is causing long shutdown delays, You might try disabling ipv6, see if the error stops logging.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852

.